# Why do I get zero as the result for my PairTester class?

Tags: java, math

Every time I run my PairTester class I keep getting zero for each result. Can anyone tell me why?

```
public class Pair {
    private double val1;
    private double val2;

    public Pair(double aFirst, double aSecond) {
        aFirst = val1;
        aSecond = val2;
    }

    public double getSum() {
        double sum = val1 + val2;
        return sum;
    }

    public double getDifference() {
        double difference = val1 - val2;
        return difference;
    }

    public double getProduct() {
        double product = val1 * val2;
        return product;
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        double average = (val1 + val2) / 2;
        return average;
    }

    public double getAbsolute() {
        double absolute = Math.abs(val1 - val2);
        return absolute;
    }

    public double getMinimum() {
        double minimum = Math.min(val1, val2);
        return minimum;
    }

    public double getMaximum() {
        double maximum = Math.max(val1, val2);
        return maximum;
    }
}
```

---

This is my tester class:

```
public class PairTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pair myPair = new Pair(11, 15);
        System.out.println("Sum = " + myPair.getSum());
        System.out.println("Difference = " + myPair.getDifference());
        System.out.println("Average = " + myPair.getAverage());
        System.out.println("Absolute = " + myPair.getAbsolute());
        System.out.println("Minimum = " + myPair.getMinimum());
        System.out.println("Maximum = " + myPair.getMaximum());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your assignments in constructor are  reversed and due to which your instance fields are not getting initialized as desired.:

Change this

```
public Pair (double aFirst, double aSecond)
{
    aFirst = val1;
    aSecond = val2;
}
```

to:

```
public Pair (double aFirst, double aSecond)
{
    val1 = aFirst;
    val2 = aSecond;
}
```

As no values were assigned to `val1` and `val2` instance fields so these fields will be initialized to `double` default value that is `0.0d`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you've assigned the instance fields to you parameters of your constructor

```
public class Pair
{
    private double val1;
    private double val2;

    public Pair (double aFirst, double aSecond)
    {
        aFirst = val1;
        aSecond = val2;
    }
```

`val1` and `val2` will be initialised to `0` automatically

Try using

```
    public Pair (double aFirst, double aSecond)
    {
        val1 = aFirst;
        val2 = aSecond;
    }
```

instead....

Answer (score 0):

From your code, we can see that you have initialized the val1 and val2 values with instance fields. Default value of any instance fields is zero. That is why you always get zero as the result for your PairTester class.

```
public Pair (double aFirst, double aSecond)
{
    aFirst = val1;
    aSecond = val2;
}
```

Try to change (Correct way)

```
public Pair (double aFirst, double aSecond)
{
    val1 = aFirst;
    val2 = aSecond;
}
```

It is recommended to use

```
public Pair (double val1, double val2)
{
    this.val1 = val1;
    this.val2 = val2;
}
```

so next time you wont be confuse

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the constructor to this

```
public Pair (double aFirst, double aSecond)
{
    val1 = aFirst;
    val2 = aSecond;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And I really thought I had this nailed down...the problems of a beginner! Haha!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public Pair (double aFirst, double aSecond)
{
    val1 = aFirst;
    val2 = aSecond;
}
```